# Call the mounted lifecycle again

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I currently have a table that uses `v-for` to populate the data

```
<table v-for="(data, idx) in dataset" :key="idx">
</table>
```

Then, I have two buttons that insert or delete certain things in the database after which I would like to re-populate the table to reflect these new changes.

So far, the data is captured from an API that is called in the `mounted` lifecycle.

```
mounted: function (){ 
     axios.get(....).then((response => {
           this.dataset = response.data;
     });
}
```

Hence, is it possible to re-call the `mounted` function to call the API and thus re-running the `v-for`?

Comment: how do you know when needs to be re-mounted?  uses `websocket` or you'd like to use `setInterval` to keep calling the API?

Answer (score 4):

You can just extract your loading logic into a method that can be called from multiple locations:

```js
const Comp = {
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      axios.get(....).then(response => {
        this.dataset = response.data;
      });
    },
    onSomeOtherAction() {
      // Do stuff.
      this.fetchData();
    },
  },
  mounted() { 
    this.fetchData();
  },
}
```

Comment: fetchData needs to return a promise in order to be composed well with other functions.